# How to make the scope of an instance of a Main class exist through the whole class

Tags: java, object, scope, instance, program-entry-point

Is it possible to make the scope of an instance of a main class exist through the whole main class? I am trying to run methods from my object classes, but the methods are in the main class.
The simplified main class looks like this

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    MyMain x = new MyMain ();
}

    public void change()
{
    System.out.println("whatever");
}

    MyMain()
{
    System.out.println("--1--");
}
```

Now if I wanted to call the method public void change from the object, I would normally just use x.change(); or MyMain.x.change; in the object, but the scope of x is obviously not reaching the object. Is there a way make the scope bigger for the object while only saying MyMain x = new MyMain(); once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make x a static variable:

```
private static MyMain x = new MyMain();
```

or make the change function static, so you don't need an instance to call it:

```
public static void change() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass main object as dependency to other objects. Or better segregate an interface (something like IChangeable) and pass it instead of actual object.

As a workaround you could make main object a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You have to options for growing the scope. Either you pass a refernce to MyMain into every object that should call a method from there, or you add a static variable holding your MyMain.

The first approach could be easily done because probably it creates all other objects. So it would be easy to write `new Foo(this)` instead of `new Foo()`. This is called Inversion of Control.

The other method would in-fact introduce a global variable. This pattern is called singleton-pattern.
Look here for an implementation: (first hit from google)
http://radio-weblogs.com/0122027/stories/2003/10/20/implementingTheSingletonPatternInJava.html